# INDEX() equivalent for MS Power BI

Tags: powerbi, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have multiple dashboards using the `INDEX()` function in Tableau. I am migrating the dashboards from Tableau to Power BI. I am looking for a similar `INDEX()` function which will limit the number of records being displayed on a visual. Is there any?

I cannot use top N because top 10 will still show more than 10 records if the value contains duplicateion. I just need a way to display only 10 records for example.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check solution described by Alberto (using RANKX):

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/how-to-compute-index-numbers-at-top-speed/